# Position the tabs at top and body at bottom in react navigation bottom tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using Tabs using `createBottomTabNavigator`. Is there a way that the tabs section comes at the top and the tab page body at the bottom like in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`?
I don't wish to use `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` because it looks different and has a different transition and animation from my requirement.

something like `tabBarPosition` in `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`

Answer (score 0):

you can use screenOptions with tabbar style to customize it

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
     ->     position: 'absolute',
top:0,}}>
```